# Getting the prime/next state of a variable

Tags: event-b

Given some condition, I want to check that a variables next state holds for some proposition. I have not been able to create something that rodin has accepted.

My exact case is the following invariant. I want to make sure that the variable `door` never changes when the lock is on. The variable `door` is either `Open` or `Closed`

```
inv4: PrimaryLock = On ⇒ door :∣ door' = door
```

If the `PrimaryLock` is `On` this means that the door state will not change, no matter what event is triggered next.

Is this possible using Event-b or do I need to solve my issue by adding additional variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the only place where you can specify properties about state changes is in events themselfes. Thus, you have to add the guard `PrimaryLock /= On` to each event that modifies the variable `door`.

If you work with refinement (you should! :), then this is actually not that bad because you specify the abstract events that might change the door and all the events in refinements must follow their specification.

```
open_door  = WHEN PrimaryLock /= On THEN door := Open   END
close_door = WHEN PrimaryLock /= On THEN door := Closed END
```

New events in refinements that do not refine `open_door` or `close_door` implicitly refine `skip` are not allowed to change the door status. So if `open_door` and `close_door` are the only events in the abstract specification that change the variable `door`, `door` can only be modified in refinements if it is not locked.

You could specify it even more abstract with

```
change_door_status = WHEN PrimaryLock /= On THEN door :: {Open,Closed} END
```

and specify the events that open or close it as refinements.

I admit that it would be a nice feature to express such properties for all events.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already have the guard set on my door changing events, so I guess that will have to do for now.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use Atelier B to develop Event-B specifications. There are some variations with respect to Rodin, but the principles remain the same.
For your issue, with Atelier B, you can specify an event as follows:

```
door_change = BEGIN
  door :( door : { Open, Closed } & 
    (PrimaryLock = On => doors = doors$0
  )
END
```

There, `door` and `door$0` stand for the values before and after the event.

You can have such an event at the most abstract level of the specification. Then, you introduce a refinement with all the events of your system that may change the state of the door and have such events refine `door_change`.

This "trick" allows one to specify properties about variable changes in the system. I do not know if this feature is available in Rodin, though.